# C# display XML from html POST

Tags: c#, .net, xml, http-post

Got a problem here... If I put the XML file on the server, then I can read it through steamReader, convert to variable and got everything working in the MSSQL database.

However, it is required that I send through html POST, and it doesn't work for the code below:

```
page.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(page.Request.InputStream);
inputString = reader.ReadToEnd();
deleteShip(inputString);
```

it seems to me that the above code didn't get the XML that POST from my program. Because for the same code in deleteShip, if I use an xml on the server then it works fine.

Is there a way to solve this problem? As long as I can send any string to deleteShip(string s) then I'm happy. The string will be in XML format though

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `page.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";` has no effect on the request.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see how the XML is POSTed to your program. Typically, data is sent from an HTML form as name-value pairs in the HTTP request body when using the POST method. It's not clear from your question whether you're using an HTML form to POST the XML to your program and it's hard to tell what might be going wrong without more information.

From your code it looks like you're reading the entire HTTP request where you'd usually read the value of a request parameter for example:

```
Request["XmlParameterName"]
```

Where `XmlParameterName` is the name of an HTML form input field.

Have you inspected the value of the `inputString` variable? Is it valid XML? Is it encoded correctly? Are any invalid characters like ampersands (&) escaped correctly?

Update your question with a bit more information if none of the things I mentioned are the problem.

Comment: It passed in from the iOS ASIHTTPRequest with appendPostData Method

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it fixed.
Here is the code.

```
System.IO.Stream stream;
string inputString;
Int32 stringLength;

stream = Request.InputStream;
stringLength = Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length);
byte[] stringArray = new byte[stringLength];

inputString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stringArray, 0, stringLength);

deleteShip(inputString);
```

By this it will access the POST body from my html request (which in this case XML).